# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::getToken()

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am trying to use excel package in my laravel 5.4 project following a tutorial I got online but I keep getting this error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::getToken() (View: 
>   C:\wamp64\www\Vidic\resources\views\file_import_export.blade.php) in
>   HtmlServiceProvider.php (line 51)

here is my composer.json file

```
{
      "name": "laravel/laravel",
      "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
      "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
    "illuminate/html": "5.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
}
```

and this is my app.php file

```
     'providers' => [
    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    ...

    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',

    'aliases' => [
    ...
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Excel' => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel',
    'Form' => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
    'HTML' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
],
];
```

and this is my view

```
            <body>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
 <div class="panel-heading">Payments</div>
  <div class="panel-body"> 
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <a href="{{ route('excel-file',['type'=>'xls']) }}">Download Excel xls</a> |
        <a href="{{ route('excel-file',['type'=>'xlsx']) }}">Download Excel xlsx</a> |
        <a href="{{ route('excel-file',['type'=>'csv']) }}">Download CSV</a>
      </div>
   </div>     
       {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'import-csv-excel','method'=>'POST','files'=>'true')) !!}
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('sample_file','Select File to Import:',['class'=>'col-md-3']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                    {!! Form::file('sample_file', array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                    {!! $errors->first('sample_file', '<p class="alert alert-danger">:message</p>') !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
            {!! Form::submit('Upload',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
       {!! Form::close() !!}
 </div>
</div>
```

I have renamed most of the methods in the HtmServiceProvider.php file such as the bindShared() to singleton() but that has not helped.
I have shortened the codes to make them easily understandable

Comment: I have gotten the form to load but when clicking on import I get this error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Excel' not found
in DebitController.php (line 89)

Comment: After importing excel facade, I got other errors and lost hope only to solve it later

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try using this tutorial instead. Find it [Here](https://medium.com/@krunallathiya/import-and-export-data-into-csv-and-excel-in-laravel-5-cfb9e00eb12a)

Comment: Looks like that tutorial has been deleted.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me: changing `getToken()` to `token()`

[Here is where I found my answer.](https://github.com/patricktalmadge/bootstrapper/issues/320)

Answer (score -1):

1 - In Your Project go to the following file;

**vendor\laravelcollective\html\src\HtmlServiceProvider.php**

2- In **registerFormBuilder()** method/function, change **getToken()** to **token()**

I hope it should work for you too.

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to change anything in laravel source files.